# WPF: dynamic menu with buttons

Tags: wpf, button, mvvm, menu

I have a simple wpf-mvvm application where you can create and edit records. Something like this:

[image: example]

If you create a new record there are a "create" and "cancel" button.
If you edit an existing record there is a "edit", "delete" and "cancel" button.

I don't want to use two different form. I would like to use one, and create a dynamic menu, where I can choose which buttons are visible.

The xaml now is something like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button MinWidth="93" Command="{Binding CreateCommand}>
        Create
    </Button>
    <Button MinWidth="93" Command="{Binding EditCommand}>
        Edit
    </Button>
    <Button MinWidth="93" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}>
        Delete
    </Button>
    <Button MinWidth="93" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}>
        Cancel
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: I posted an answer, are you using an MVVM framework? Do you have access to a DelegateCommand of sorts? (A command you can create to pass in a method / lambda easily for Execute and CanExecute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar situation. There are two options (at least, as always):

---

Use the **CanExecute** method of the commands and let them return true or false, depending on the type of record you want to edit. The `CanExecute` value toggles the `IsEnabled` property of the control it is bound to. This means, if you want to hide the control, you need to 'push' the `IsEnabled` value to the `Visibility` value, for example by using a style trigger.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

That would be the standard approach, I guess, and probably makes sense for you.

---

I had more dynamic circumstances and wanted to create the buttons dynamically. This can easily be done, when you define a **Collection of CommandViewModels** in your ViewModel. The CommandViewModel can have a name property which you display in a button and the command you want to execute. Then you can use this collection to populate an ItemsControl with buttons. Probably a bit of a overkill for your situation, but it refers to the title of your question and maybe you find it interesting and can use it at some point.

In short, the ViewModels:

```
public class CommandViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   public ICommand Command { get { return ... } }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   ...
   ObservableCollection<CommandViewModel> Commands { get; private set; }

   public MainViewModel()
   {
      Commands = new ObservableCollection<CommandViewModel>();
      // Creates the ViewModels for the commands you want to offer
      PopulateCommands();
   }
}
```

And in the XAML looks something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}"}>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Button Command="{Binding Command}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

That makes a dynamic menu...

---

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM, then you have a ViewModel which is your DataContext which contains the Create, edit, delete, and cancel commands.

Have your ViewModel have an instance of a record. If you edit it, pass in the instance to be edited. Else for creating a record set that to null.

Create your commands and have the CanExecute functionality check if the record that was passed in was null or not. (null represents Creating a new record, else editing). If you set the CanExecute of your commands to false, the buttons bound to it will automatically be disabled.